# Is there a way to catch a keyboard event in a dll?

Tags: c#, events, dll

I need to execute a specific code when user presses some keys from keyboard.

Nothing hard until now, i should do this in a dll project type, class library, and do not use any specific windows forms controls.

Could this be achieved ? , if so please provide me some some examples or learning materials.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `GetKeyboardState` API function.

```
[DllImport ("user32.dll")]
public static extern int GetKeyboardState( byte[] keystate );


private void Form1_KeyDown( object sender, KeyEventArgs e )
{
   byte[] keys = new byte[255];

   GetKeyboardState (keys);

   if( keys[(int)Keys.Up] == 129 && keys[(int)Keys.Right] == 129 )
   {
       Console.WriteLine ("Up Arrow key and Right Arrow key down.");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a [keylogger](http://www.axino.net/tutorial/2009/02/keylogger-in-c-introduction)?

Comment: Since all the hook functionality is being P/Invoke'd in from the native Windows API, what's the point of writing the DLL in C#?

Comment: @slavik262, because .NET doesn't provide similar functionality.

Comment: I mean as opposed to C/C++. You could write all the same code, nearly line for line, in C++. The DLL wouldn't be dependent on the .NET framework, would be arguably faster, and wouldn't have to invoke native calls through a managed language.

Comment: @slavik262, probably the OP is looking for a way to consume this DLL from a managed application. If you write it in unmanaged code you will have to do the P/Invoke in order to consume it.

Comment: True, but you'd only have to do a single P/Invoke to set up the hook and another one to take it down. Writing the hook itself in .NET requires native functionality to be invoked on every single keystroke (for `CallNextHookEx`).

Comment: @slavik262, that's true. I did it for a project of mine and didn't have any issues or performance problems with it. Of course tests need to be performed.

Comment: No, i am not trying to create a key logger, i am trying to respond to some drawing events which are not done to a Windows Form.

Comment: @Darin - I'm not saying that doing it in C# won't work, just that C# probably isn't the tool of choice for the job.


@Mircea - Regardless of what you want to do with the input, hooks are the only way to get keyboard input when your application's window isn't focused.

Answer (score 0):

You can use key [hooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get global keyboard input. Since doing it in C# will require you to P/Invoke almost all the functionality from the native API anyways, you might as well write the DLL in C/C++ and remove the .NET dependency.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot accomplish this with managed code libraries unless you want to capture key events from Windows Form Controls (`System.Windows.Forms.Control`). Otherwise you will have to import native code to handle keyboard event hooks.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way, even with P/Invoke to write a global hook in C#, only low-level keyboard and mouse hooks. So you could probably P/Invoke either the whole hook, or only a self-written C++ DLL, but in any case its a lot of work.
I would look for a way to do what you want with Hotkeys, so you don't need a hook.

Good luck, Alex